# How can I pass a scope variable into a directive's `tAttrrs` object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Alright, so I would like to use a scope variable in a dynamically generated template url. So I tried this:

html

```
<my-directive type="{{ type }}"></my-directive>
```

js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
        return 'templates/myDirective.' + tAttrs.type + '.html';
      };
    };
  });
```

I was expecting `tAttrs.type` to return the value of `$scope.type`, but instead I ended up getting `{{ type }}`. This resulted in a templateUrl of `templates/myDirective.{{ type }}.html`.

So, what can I do to get the scope variable's value instead of the raw text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope values are not accessible from within a directive's templateUrl. The attributes are not compiled yet, so from within this context it is not possible to access the scope.

Here is a workaround that might work for you.

[See Plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/7hjcI74uNnYEfCx2pqAK/preview)

What I did here is using a template containing a div with ng-include, getting the url through a two-way bind.

Comment: Nice, thanks, much easier than the route I was I trying to take. Still not perfect, but usable.