# How can I pass the name of a file to be used as a template into a dirctory?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying this:

```
app.directive('adminTemplate', ['stateService', function (stateService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            src: "="
        },

        templateUrl: src,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.stateService = stateService;
        }
    };
}]);
```

But it's giving me an error with Typescript saying "Could not find symbol src".

How can I get the template and how could I call it with this directive?

Comment: and scope.src? You access that value in this way, like in the example number 2: (http://pucksart.com/angularjs-isolate-scope/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope values are not accessible from within a directive's templateUrl. The attributes are not compiled yet, so from within this context it is not possible to access the scope.

[Please check my answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25467324/2144711) or the [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/Hly57DhAW25qLtfKPg9B/)

What I did there is using a template containing a div with ng-include.