# AngularJS - directive with dynamic template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, dynamic, directive

I'm wondering - how to make a `Directive` with dynamic template. 
The thing is - When I'm on the main page and main categories like `page1` or `page2` my template should have all the `divs`

When I'm on the submenu like `subpage1` or `subpage2` I want to have only `3 divs`.
How to dynamically achieve it? I know that I have to use on each subpage my directive

`<my-template whereIam="page1"></my-template>` or `<my-template whereIam="subpage2"></my-template>`

But I can't achieve it. Could you help me?

My directive with example template:

```
angular.module('dynamic-template').directive('myTemplate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<div1> "
                    + "<h1> Main pages and subpages </h1>"
                + "</div1>"
                + "<div2>"
                    + "<h2> Main pages and subpages </h2>"
                + "</div2>"
                + "<div3>"
                    + "<h3> Main pages and subpages </h3>"
                + "</div3>"
                + "<div4>"
                    + "<h4> Only mainpages </h4>"
                + "</div4>"
                + "<div5>"
                    + "<h5> Only subpages </h5>"
                + "</div5>"                     
    };
}]);
```

HTML on one of the pages:

`<my-template whereIam="??" ></menu-template>`

Example Plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/kVk3mJWUbTqhFEHVUjt1?p=preview

I have searched for this, but I'm lost :(

Have I use a $compile to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*note: Personally I prefer having the template in a separate file (use templateUrl)

but well...

You can pass through the page-type of page and use ng-if's.

```
angular.module('dynamic-template').directive('myTemplate', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { isMain: "=main"},
    template: "<div1> "
                + "<h1> Main pages and subpages </h1>"
            + "</div1>"
            + "<div2>"
                + "<h2> Main pages and subpages </h2>"
            + "</div2>"
            + "<div3>"
                + "<h3> Main pages and subpages </h3>"
            + "</div3>"
            + "<span ng-if='isMainPage'><div4>"
                + "<h4> Only mainpages </h4>"
            + "</div4>"
            + "<div5>"
                + "<h5> Only mainpages </h5>"
            + "</div5></span>"                     
};
}]);
```

and in your html (when it is a main page)

> ```
> <my-template main="true"/>
> ```

---

Otherwise, my answer on a similar question might work fine for you:

This way of doing it does require you to create separate html files for each file

[See other Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466394/how-can-i-pass-a-scope-variable-into-a-directives-tattrrs-object/25467324#25467324)

or the Plunkr directly

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7hjcI74uNnYEfCx2pqAK?p=preview)

```
app.directive('myDirective', [function(){

return {
    template: '<div ng-include="getTemplate()"></div>',
    restrict: 'E',
scope: {template: '='},
link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
  var baseURL = 'templates/myDirective.'

  scope.getTemplate = function(){
      baseURL = "" //remove this
      return baseURL + scope.template + ".html"
    };
}
};
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but -  I have updated my Plunkr and your solution (based on ng-if) doesn't work :(

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake in my code, sorry.
One last question - what if I want to display one header only in subpage?

Comment: You can do the same :) <h1 ng-if="!isMainPage">I am a sub page header</h1>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Why not do as rmuller said and use a templateURL, but you can pass in the param and return the correct template example

```
templateUrl: function (elem, attrs) {
                if (attrs.isMain === 'mainPage') {
                    return 'main_view.html';
                }
                return 'other_view.html';
            },
```

So you would seperate out your templates into files. I think this would be the best way in my own opinion

Comment: Yes, I'm trying also with templateUrl, but for now I'm testing simple `template`. Also thank you for help!